# Similarity between time series groups

Tags: python, for-loop, pyspark, time-series

I have a dataset like the below, multiple groups, completed values with over 200 columns (denoting days)

Input

| Series | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | GROUP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/08/2021 | 100% | 75% | 60% | 50% | 40% | 30% | 0% | A |
| 08/08/2021 | 100% | 95% | 80% | 60% | 30% | 10% | 0% | A |
| 15/08/2021 | 100% | 85% | 60% | 40% | 20% | 10% | 5% | A |
| 01/08/2021 | 100% | 70% | 65% | 55% | 45% | 35% | 0% | B |
| 08/08/2021 | 100% | 90% | 80% | 60% | 30% | 10% | 0% | B |
| 15/08/2021 | 100% | 95% | 60% | 40% | 30% | 20% | 5% | B |

Now, I have an incomplete dataset like the below. I would like to compute similarity metric for each group and state which series is most similar.

For purpose of similarity, I am using CORREL in Excel at the moment and in case of tie, I am using the latest one. For comparison, only complete  values in both groups are compared (i.e. so missing values in expected output are not used for similarity metric calculation).

This is a VBA macro which I am shifting to python (either pandas or pyspark).

I am confused on how best to proceed. Any other similarity metric can be tried out too. Thanks

Expected Output

| Series | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | Similarity_Score | Similarity_Week | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/09/2021 |  |  |  |  | 39% | 28% | 0% | 0.99 | 01/08/2021 | A |
| 08/09/2021 |  |  | 62% | 44% | 21% | 12% | 7% | 0.99 | 15/08/2021 | A |
| 15/09/2021 |  |  |  |  |  | 8% | 0% | 1.00 | 08/08/2021 | A |
| 15/09/2021 |  |  |  |  | 30% | 19% | 0% | 1.00 | 15/08/2021 | B |

Comment: This seems like multiple questions.  You are more likely to get helpful advice if you focus on one thing, and have a go at showing at least a partial solution.  With respect to Expected Output, I had trouble understanding how those value were derived from the Input.

Answer (score 0):

This solution involves iterating over each group, taking a subset of each dataframe and taking the product of each dataframes values, such that each row can be compared to every other row.

We can use some nested zip/filter/reverse trickery to keep only columns that are filled out.  Putting that in a list with the dates from both dfs and the group, we can create a dataframe, sort, group, and keep the top score from each.

Joining this back to the second df should give you the output you want.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

df = pd.DataFrame({'Series': {0: '01/08/2021',
  1: '08/08/2021',
  2: '15/08/2021',
  3: '01/08/2021',
  4: '08/08/2021',
  5: '15/08/2021'},
 '1': {0: '100%', 1: '100%', 2: '100%', 3: '100%', 4: '100%', 5: '100%'},
 '2': {0: '75%', 1: '95%', 2: '85%', 3: '70%', 4: '90%', 5: '95%'},
 '3': {0: '60%', 1: '80%', 2: '60%', 3: '65%', 4: '80%', 5: '60%'},
 '4': {0: '50%', 1: '60%', 2: '40%', 3: '55%', 4: '60%', 5: '40%'},
 '5': {0: '40%', 1: '30%', 2: '20%', 3: '45%', 4: '30%', 5: '30%'},
 '6': {0: '30%', 1: '10%', 2: '10%', 3: '35%', 4: '10%', 5: '20%'},
 '7': {0: '0%', 1: '0%', 2: '5%', 3: '0%', 4: '0%', 5: '5%'},
 'GROUP': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'B', 5: 'B'}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Series': {0: '01/09/2021',
  1: '08/09/2021',
  2: '15/09/2021',
  3: '15/09/2021'},
 '1': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan},
 '2': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan},
 '3': {0: np.nan, 1: '62%', 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan},
 '4': {0: np.nan, 1: '44%', 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan},
 '5': {0: '39%', 1: '21%', 2: np.nan, 3: '30%'},
 '6': {0: '28%', 1: '12%', 2: '8%', 3: '19%'},
 '7': {0: '0%', 1: '7%', 2: '0%', 3: '0%'},
 'Similarity_Score': {0: 0.99, 1: 0.99, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0},
 'Similarity_Week': {0: '01/08/2021',
  1: '15/08/2021',
  2: '08/08/2021',
  3: '15/08/2021'},
 'Group': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'B'}}
)

df2.drop(columns=['Similarity_Score','Similarity_Week'], inplace=True)


l = []
for g, data in df.groupby('GROUP'):
    x = df2.loc[df2['Group']==g]
    for c in product(data.values,x.values):
        a = c[0][1:-1]
        b = c[1][1:-1]
        a,b = list(zip(*(zip(reversed(a),list(filter(lambda v: v==v, b))))))
        a = [int(x.replace('%',''))/100 for x in a]
        b = list(reversed([int(x.replace('%',''))/100 for x in b]))
        l.append([g,c[0][0],c[1][0], np.corrcoef(a,b)[1,0]])

out = df2.merge(pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['Group','Similarity_Week','Series','Similarity_Score']).sort_values(by=['Similarity_Score', 'Similarity_Week'], ascending=False).groupby(['Group','Series']).head(1), on=['Group','Series'])
```

Output

```
       Series   1   2    3    4    5    6   7 Group Similarity_Week  \
0  01/09/2021 NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  39%  28%  0%     A      01/08/2021   
1  08/09/2021 NaN NaN  62%  44%  21%  12%  7%     A      15/08/2021   
2  15/09/2021 NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   8%  0%     A      01/08/2021   
3  15/09/2021 NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  30%  19%  0%     B      15/08/2021   

   Similarity_Score  
0          0.999405  
1          0.999005  
2          1.000000  
3          0.999286
```

I believe the scores are very similar for 15/09/2021 group A, such that if you were to round the scores you would get a different most recent date.  You can validate this by checking

```
[x for x in l if x[2]=='15/09/2021' and x[0]=='A']
```

Yields

```
[['A', '01/08/2021', '15/09/2021', 1.0],
 ['A', '08/08/2021', '15/09/2021', 0.9999999999999998],
 ['A', '15/08/2021', '15/09/2021', 0.9999999999999998]]
```

So in theory the 15/08/2021 would be the date if you were rounding to a few decimal places, which you could do by putting `round()` around the `np.corrcoef`

Comment: thanks a lot. This works very well, let me try this on the bigger dataset and get back to you. Appreciate if you can explain the for loop. Thanks a lot again

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a solution without `for` loops you could `merge` the two data frames on `Group`, and use `groupby` to apply the similarity metric.

Building on the data frames constructed by @Chris:

```
df.rename(columns={"GROUP":"Group"}, inplace=True)

def similarity(arr1, arr2):
        """Similarity between two arrays of percent strings, nans ignored"""

    df = pd.DataFrame({"arr1":arr1, "arr2":arr2}).dropna() \
            .apply(lambda s: s.str.strip("%").astype(float)/100)
    return df.arr1.corr(df.arr2)

# Convert data columns to array in each row.
df_xformed = df.set_index(["Series", "Group"]).apply(pd.Series.to_numpy, axis=1) \
                .reset_index().rename(columns={"Series":"df_Series", 0:"df"})
df2_xformed = df2.set_index(["Series", "Group"]).apply(pd.Series.to_numpy, axis=1) \
                .reset_index().rename(columns={"Series":"df2_Series", 0:"df2"})

# Merge on Group and calculate similarities.
df_combined = df_xformed.merge(df2_xformed, on="Group")
df_combined["similarity"] = df_combined.apply(
    lambda row: similarity(row["df"], row["df2"]), axis=1)

# Find max similarity of each df2_Series within its Group.
df_combined["df2_sim_max"] = df_combined.groupby(\
                                 ["df2_Series", "Group"])["similarity"] \
                                .transform(max)

idx = df_combined["similarity"] == df_combined["df2_sim_max"]
result = df_combined[idx][["df2_Series", "Group", "df2", "df_Series", "similarity"]]
result
#     df2_Series Group  ...   df_Series similarity
# 0   01/09/2021     A  ...  01/08/2021   0.999405
# 2   15/09/2021     A  ...  01/08/2021   1.000000
# 7   08/09/2021     A  ...  15/08/2021   0.999005
# 11  15/09/2021     B  ...  15/08/2021   0.999286
```

Comment: Wow very interesting and I understand your solution too. Much appreciated TMBailey./